How to write unit test case for reactive form in angular 18
I am new for unit test case in angular.I am trying to write unit test case for angular reactive fomr. But, It is not working properly.
Getting below error some times


Error: NG01052: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. Example: <div [formGroup]="myGroup">   In your class: this.myGroup = new
FormGroup({ firstName: new FormControl() });


3 test case also failed. How to resolve these issue. If anyone knows, Please help to find the solution.
my-input.component.spec.ts:
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { MyInputComponent } from './my-input.component';
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

describe('MyInputComponent', () => {
  let component: MyInputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyInputComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ReactiveFormsModule, provideMockStore()],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it('should call ngOnInit', () => {
    const expectedFormGroup = new FormBuilder().group({
      fullname: ['', Validators.required],
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    component.form=expectedFormGroup;
    expect(component.form).toEqual(expectedFormGroup);
  });


  it('should call to set form value', () => {
    component.form.setValue({
      fullname:'test' ,
      username: 'testd' ,
      email: 'test@gmail.com'
    });
    expect(component.form.valid).toEqual(true);
  });

   
});

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jtk35tru?file=src%2Fmy-input-component%2Fmy-input.component.spec.ts
